# Can I add a file shared on Slack to Google Drive without downloading manually?

Tags: google-drive, slack

There is a Drive app for Slack that seems able to let me share Drive docs on Slack but not, as far as I can tell, the converse. Our customer likes to share files on Slack, which we then download and add to our GDrive for safe-keeping.

Is there any way from Slack I can send the file directly to GDrive

Comment: If the shared files can be downloaded without loging in to Slack, how about using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)? Of course, even if the files cannot be downloaded without the authorization, you can download the files using the access token retrieved from Slack.

Comment: Maybe this? https://zapier.com/apps/google-drive/integrations/slack/60850/upload-google-drive-files-from-new-slack-files

Comment: (That template doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any existing Slack apps that automatically sends all files uploaded on Slack to a Google Drive. But you could easily create your own Slack app for that.

The basic functional outline would be:

1. Listen to [message](https://api.slack.com/events/message) events of a channel with Slack's [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api)
2. Detect a file upload
3. Download the file to your local server storage
4. Upload the file to your Google Drive account via [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload)
5. Delete the file from your server storage
6. Optionally: Send a notification to someone about the upload of another file

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [odrive](https://www.odrive.com/) to sync all Slack files to my local machine, and then putting them on Drive manually.  Could probably use a symlink or something to get one folder to sync with the other.